# ListView is slicing the bottom row in half

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

For some reason the ListView won't display the contents fully. The bottom every time, is cut off halfway. There are other ListViews in the same app where this is happening too.

That's what's happening in this app. The window on the app that lets us see the listview is two small for the listview itself.

Here's what it looks like in the app:

[image: The List view is scrolled to the bottom, but the frame of the list view doesn't display the bottom.]

Here's the XML for this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:columnCount="7"
        android:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgcolorsquarehat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/bluesquare" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Numberhat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="49"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Computer Science BSc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgcolorsquarehat"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/red_thumb" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/padlock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/padlock_button"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
</GridLayout>
```

EDIT: See below an image of where the ListView thinks its boundaries should be.

[image: This is how big the list view *thinks* it is.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a ListView inside a GridView, both are subclasses of AbsListView.
Instead you could use a LinearLayout for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="3">
...
```

Comment: Did you *just* remove the padding?

Comment: I've updated the post with more info if you have any other ideas! Corrected one of the images.

Comment: I just saw that I misunderstood your problem. Of course removing the padding doesn't solve it. Instead you should just use a LinearLayout instead Gridview

Comment: I'll try it after I've had my curry!

Comment: If you post it as an answer, then I can decide later whether to mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `android:layout_margin="10dp"` on the `ListView` is the culprit. Try removing that and seeing what happens.

Comment: No luck sadly … In fact, even *more* of the row is sliced off!

Comment: @MiKenning What happens if you remove the android:padding="10dp" from the GridLayout?

Comment: I got more of the row back, but I have the same problem!

Comment: @MiKenning And if you remove both is it the same result?

Comment: The same result, I'm afraid

Comment: I've updated the post with more info if you have any other ideas! Corrected one of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Try using and changing the android:layout_margin and android:padding attributes, try multiple values to adjust the views on the screen, or even better, adjust the height of the Child views.

Comment: I've tried removing the padding. The number of other views doesn't matter given that I have this problem elsewhere in the app.

Comment: I didn't mean the Child View Numbers, i mean, the Height for each child on the list. Try to get youf ListView height, and then, calculate how many childs will fit on that space.

Comment: How exactly would I calculate that?

Comment: I've updated the post with more info if you have any other ideas! Corrected one of the images.